# "Attempt to index local 'self' (a nil value)" cant index variables of my classes

Tags: lua

I know this question already exists a couple of times on this site, BUT my problem is a little different! So... see my problem is that im trying to get a value in a draw function i wrote for my player class but when im trying to get anything with self.such'n'such it says attempt to index local 'self' (a nil value) the functions arent important for my problem (I hope)

```
require"functions"
Acc = 2000
Decel = 2500
Maxspd = 900

Player = {}
Player.__index = Player

function Player:new(x,y)
    local play = {}
    setmetatable(play, Player)
    play.inx = 0
    play.iny = 0
    play.dirx = 0
    play.diry = 0
    play.x = x
    play.y = y
    play.speedx = 0
    play.speedy = 0
    play.velx = 0
    play.vely = 0
    play.clr = "red"
    play.hp = 100
    play.rot = 0
    play.size = 40
    play.hoehe = math.sqrt(3) * (40 / 2)
    return play
end

function love.load()
    Main = Player:new(100,100)
end

function Player:update(d)
    if love.keyboard.isDown("w") then self.iny = -1
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown("s") then self.iny = 1 else self.iny = 0 end
    if love.keyboard.isDown("d") then self.inx = 1 
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown("a") then self.inx = -1 else self.inx = 0 end
    if self.inx == -self.dirx then self.speedx = self.speedx / 5 end
    if self.iny == -self.diry then self.speedy = self.speedy / 5 end
    self.dirx = self.inx
    self.diry = self.iny
    if self.inx ~= 0 then self.speedx = self.speedx + Acc * d
        else self.speedx = self.speedx - Decel * d end
    if self.iny ~= 0 then self.speedy = self.speedy + Acc * d
        else self.speedy = self.speedy - Decel * d end
    self.speedx = clamp(self.speedx,0,Maxspd)
    self.speedy = clamp(self.speedy,0,Maxspd)
    self.velx = self.speedx * d * self.dirx
    self.vely = self.speedy * d * self.diry
    self.x = self.x * d
    self.y = self.y * d
end

function Player:getX() return self.x end
function Player:getY() return self.y end

function Player:switch()
    if self.clr == "red" then self.clr = "blue" end
    if self.clr == "blue" then self.clr = "red" end
end

function Player:draw()
    local x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3 = 0,0,0,0,0,0
    x1 = self.x - self.size / 2
    y1 = self.y + self.hoehe / 2
    x2 = self.x + self.size/2
    y2 = self.y + self.hoehe / 2
    x3 = self.x
    y3 = self.y - self.hoehe / 2
    x1, y1 = rotate_around_point(x1, y1, self.x, self.y, self.rot)
    x2, y2 = rotate_around_point(x2, y2, self.x, self.y, self.rot)
    x3, y3 = rotate_around_point(x3, y3, self.x, self.y, self.rot)
    local verts = {x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3}
    if self.clr == "blue" then love.graphics.setColor(0,255,0,1) end
    if self.clr == "red" then love.graphics.setColor(255,0,0,1) end
    love.graphics.polygon("fill",verts)
end

function love.keypressed(key,scancode,isrepeat)
    if key == "space" then Main:switch() end
end

function love.update(d)
    Main:update(d)
end

function love.draw()
    Main.draw()
end
```

Comment: Probably, you are invoking your functions as `x.f()` instead of `x:f()`

Comment: Im not trying to invoke a function im trying to get the value of a variable

Comment: @NiclasWerther Egor is saying that you're invoking the `draw()` function as `x.draw()` instead of as `x:draw()`, which is why `self` inside of `draw()` is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and @EgorSkriptunoff's answer was dead on; going to post here as an answer rather than a comment for posterity.

> Probably, you are invoking your functions as x.f() instead of x:f()